# Extract information within tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn BeautifulSoup but it takes a time. I hope you can help me with this.
In the code below, the same syntax is repeated several times and I would like to know how to create a list with: First item,Second item,....N:th item
The logic should be to find "title=" (which is unique) and then extract the string to the right of "title=". Probably very easy if you know how to do it...

```
<td align=left valign="top" class="small" title="First item" nowrap>
<td align=left valign="top" class="small" title="Second item" nowrap>
<td align=left valign="top" class="small" title="N:th item" nowrap>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: I have tried to use the soup.findAll('td', attrs={X : Y}) but I do knot know how to find title=. I know how to handle it if I would like to find title="First Item" but not how to find title= and then extract "First item".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to find the elements containing title, you can get the titles by using `elem['title']`.

To get a titles as a list:

```
titlelist=[elem['title'] for elem in soup.findAll('td', attrs={X : Y})]
```

EDIT: As you said you can find the elements containing titles you want by using `soup.findAll('td', attrs={X : Y})`, this code is basically a for loop, that goes through the list of elements produced by `soup.findAll('td', attrs={X : Y})` and gets the value of the title attribute. The same as:

```
elements = `soup.findAll('td', attrs={X : Y})`
titlelist=[]
for elem in elements:
    titlelist.append(elem['title'])
```

if you just want to find elems that have the attribute `title`, use `has_key()`:

```
    elements = `soup.findAll('td')`
    titlelist=[]
    for elem in elements:
        if elem.has_key('title'):
            titlelist.append(elem['title'])
    print titlelist
```

Comment: Too short and complex for me to understand, is it possible to get a short explainaition. What I really want is to find "title=" and then extract the string to the right of "title=".

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work. Is it not possible to somehow find the string "title=" in the document and then from there extract the information? I have tried tis but it does not work... soup.find(text="title="). Returns None.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get an error message? Can you give us the url of the page?

Comment: The attrs I can use is align=left valign="top" class="small" and these are not unique I do not know how to format X and Y. I know that I want to search for title= (not title) which is unique for this page and the return the string to the right of title=.

Comment: it is hard to understand your problem. give us a link to the page and tell us what is the output you want to get.

Comment: The page is very long and every tenth (approx) row there there is a row that looks like above "<td align=left valign="top" class="small" title="First item" nowrap>". I want to find all these row and the uniqe identifier  for the row is title= (if I surch the whole page for title=, these are the only rows I find). When I have found the rows I want to extract the information to the right of title= which in the example is "First item" and put this into a list that contains "First item", "Second item" etc. Note that the unique identifier for the row is title= (not title without =).

Comment: This code made it. I do not rally understand why but it works...tds=soup.findAll('td',{'title':re.compile("")})
the_td = tds[1].text.strip()

Comment: now that i understand what you mean, you can also use has_key('title'), to check if the element has an attribute named title.

Answer (score 1):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = 'http://www.somewebsite.com/'
file_pointer = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_pointer)

td_list = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'small')
for td in td_list:
    print td.contents[0]
```

This should work, but without knowing the other contents of the site, its hard to say. Also, this assumes there is text content in the `td` tag. If you need other code, say to access a `<span>` or what not, other code is required, but this should help start you off.

Comment: Thanks, it is the exact string "title=" that is unique for the page, not the other attributes such as class="small". This is only a short extract of the page and is is only "title=" that is unique (title exists at several places but nnot title=).

Comment: Aah, ok! Sorry about that! I misunderstood the question, then =)